# URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] # Unable to import Seaborn inbuilt dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

'''
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

'''

*************Getting Error*********************

unable to import seaborn inbuilt dataset.

URL Error: <URL open error [Win Error 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
'''